# TMessage: Call to a member function CheckUser() on null

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

**controller**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

  class Login extends CI_Controller {
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->load->model('MUser');
     }

         public function index()
         {
          if ($this->session->userdata('logged') == true ) {
            redirect('rental') ;           
          }else{
            $this->load->view('login');
          }
         }

             public function validasi()
              {
                $this->load->library('Form_validation');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

                    if($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
                      $username = $this->input->post('username');
                       $password = $this->input->post('password');

                        if($this->MUser->CheckUser ($username,$password) == true) {
                          $data = array('username'=>$username, 'logged'=> true);
                          $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                            redirect('rental');

                        }else{
                          $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', 'Username atau password anda salah');

                             redirect('Login');
                       }

                    } else {
                      $this->load->view('login');
                    }    
              }

              public function logout()
              {
                $this->session->session_destroy();
                redirect('Login', 'referesh');
              }
            }
  ?>
```

**model**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

   class MUser extends CI_Model {
      public $table = "user";
      public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
     }
       public function CheckUser($username, $password) {
       $query = $this->db->get_where($this->table, array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));
          if($query->num_rows() > 0)
          {
             return true;
          } else {
             return false;
          }
       }
   }
   ?>
```

**An uncaught Exception was encountered**

Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function CheckUser() on null

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\rental\application\controllers\Login.php

Line Number: 30

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\rental\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

pliss answer my question

Comment: What question? All there is here is some source and an error message.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You can't just dump your code here with an error message if you expect to get a helpful response.

Comment: Please tell us which line is 30.

Comment: Here's a free hint though: `__construct()` should have *two* underscores.

Comment: Looks like you are verifying a plan password in your database not a good idea use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php to create a password  and then use this to verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php varcahr 255 for password column

Comment: Your model file naming and class naming wrong for codeigniter read this  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model

Comment: this is wrong also  `$this->load->library('Form_validation');` should be  `$this->load->library('form_validation');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

"This wrong ini line 30"

```
 public function CheckUser($username, $password) {
   $query = $this->db->get_where($this->table, 
    array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));
      if($query->num_rows() > 0)
      {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
```